# The position of 'const' qualifier of a parameter which is passed by reference in template context

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, constants

Consider the two following prototypes:

```
template<class T>
void whatever1(const T& something);

template<class T>
void whatever2(T const& something);
```

They are both identical. Yet what if `T` is not a usual type, but a pointer type? For instance, let `T` be `Somewhere*` then `whatever1` and `whatever2` would have different interpretation:

```
// nonconst pointer (passed by reference) to const object
void whatever1(const Somewhere*& something);

// const pointer (passed by reference) to nonconst object
void whatever2(Somewhere* const& something);
```

In this case, I can infer the following properties:

**1 `whatever1`:**

a) can modify `something` inside and these changes propagate to the outside;

b) object pointed by `something` cannot be modified.

**2 `whatever2`:**

a) cannot modify `something` inside so it is safe outside;

b) object pointed by `something` can be modified.

Usually `const` and `&` are used together to avoid copying when passing a parameter and to protect this parameter from modification at the same time. Then in terms of this philosophy only `whatever2` fulfills its role. However, if I want the object pointed by `something` to be also non-modifiable, then none of two is suitable! Then what would be? Maybe this joke:

```
template<class T>
void whatever3(const T const& something);
```

In addition to this confusion some people use `whatever1` style, while others use `whatever2` one. Which one should be used when creating generic classes and methods as a rule of thumb?

Note that if we start considering `Somewhere**` as `T` things get even more confusing.

Comment: `void whatever1(const Somewhere*& something);` is not a correct translation. It would in fact be `void whatever1(Somewhere* const& something);`, the same as `whatever2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. When `T = U *`, then `T const &` and `const T &` are both `U * const &`, and that's it. Similarly, `const T` and `T const` are both `U * const`, and when `T = const W`, then `T *` is `W const *` or `const W *`. (This is all subject to reference collapsing rules, of course, so assume that neither `U` nor `W` are reference types).

Answer (score 3):

The replacement of T with Somewhere* when the template is instantiated isn't a textual one - so in both cases, the const will apply to the pointer and not the thing at which it points.

Answer (score 3):

You can't inject a `const`-qualifier into a named type that way.  As a simple example, if you have:

```
typedef int* P;
const P x;
```

Then `x` is of type `int* const`, not `const int*`.  The `const` is applied to the whole `P` type, not just to a part of the `P` type.  The same applies to template type parameters.

If you wanted to inject a `const` qualifier into the type, you can do so without too much trouble, e.g. by using type traits like `remove_pointer` and `add_const`.

Answer (score 1):

> They are both identical. Yet what if `T` is not a usual type, but a pointer type? For instance, let `T` be `Somewhere*` then `whatever1` and `whatever2` would have different interpretation:
>
> ```
> // nonconst pointer (passed by reference) to const object
> void whatever1(const Somewhere*& something);
>
> // const pointer (passed by reference) to nonconst object
> void whatever2(Somewhere* const& something);
> ```

No, actually it wouldn't be `void whatever1(const Somewhere*& something);`, it would be `void whatever1(const (Somewhere*)& something);` in invalid C++-like code. The C++ way to write it is your `whatever2`, but they mean the same thing.